# timeSeries align not finishing its job

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the timeSeries package, and especially the `align` function. My data are spurious and I want to fill the NAs by propagating the last available value. But it seems that `align()` doesn't go until the end of the sample if it finishes with an NA.

An example: I have a non-aligned time series

```
> notAligned
GMT
           TS.1 TS.2 TS.3 TS.4
2011-02-03   NA    1    4    8
2011-02-04    1   NA    2   NA
2011-02-07    5    6   NA   NA
2011-02-08   NA    2   NA    9
```

If I use the align function, it returns this

```
> align(notAligned)
GMT
           TS.1 TS.2 TS.3 TS.4
2011-02-03   NA    1    4    8
2011-02-04    1    1    2    8
2011-02-07    5    6   NA    8
2011-02-08   NA    2   NA    9
```

It correctly fills TS.2 on the 4th and TS.4 on the 4th and 7th, but doesn't fill TS.1 on the 8th with 5, or TS.3 on the 7th and 8th with 2. I would expect `align` to fill them...

Did I misunderstand the function? Is there a way to work around this?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why `timeSeries::align` doesn't work, but I would just use `zoo::na.locf`:

```
na.locf(notAligned, na.rm=FALSE)
# GMT
#            TS.1 TS.2 TS.3 TS.4
# 2011-02-03   NA    1    4    8
# 2011-02-04    1    1    2    8
# 2011-02-07    5    6    2    8
# 2011-02-08    5    2    2    9
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, it works perfectly. I actually combined it with `align` as `align` also makes the time series regular, which is not the case of `na.locf`...